# Quickblox - How to initiate QBSessionManager class

Tags: java, android, quickblox

### I wanted to import QBSessionManager class and according to QUICKBLOX documentation I import all dependencies in my app gradle, still i cannot import QBSessionManager class, can anyone tell me about which dependency is required to import this class. Thanks

```
so far I import following dependencies:
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.6.1' 
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these updated versions:

```
  compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.3.0'
  compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.0'
  compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.3.0'
  compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:3.3.0'
  compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use version 3.0 or above for newer dependencies of quickblox.